# Let $X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(2)$, $Y\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(3)$ Determine $P(X=k\mid T=n)$ and obtain $E(X|T)$ and $\sigma (X|T)$ where $T=X+Y$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

With $X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(2)$, $Y\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(3)$ being statistically independent where $T=X+Y$ the problem asks to determine:

$1.$$P(X=k\mid T=n)$ for every value of $k$ and $n$ and obtain $E(X\mid T)$ 
and $\sigma (X\mid T)$

$2.$$P(T=n\mid X=k)$ for every value of $k$ and $n$ and obtain $E(T\mid X)$ 
and $\sigma (T\mid |X)$

To find $P(X=k\mid T=n)$ I get:

\begin{align*} 
P(X=k\mid  T=n) &= \frac{P(X=k)\cap P(T=n)}{P(T=n)}  \\ 
&= \frac{P(X=k)\cap P(X+Y=n)}{P(T=n)}) \\
&= \frac{P(X=k)\cap P(Y=n-k)}{P(T=n)}
\end{align*}

but from here I'm not sure how the textbook concluded that this equals: 
\begin{align}
\binom{n}{k} (\frac{2}{5})^k (\frac{3}{5})^{n-k} = X\mid T\sim\operatorname{binomial}(T,2/5)
\end{align}
and but I get how it follows to find the expected value and $\sigma$.

And to find $P(T=n | X=k)$ I get:

\begin{align*} 
P(X=k | T=n) &= \frac{P(X=k)\cap P(T=n)}{P(X=k)}  \\ 
&= \frac{P(X=k)\cap P(Y=n-k)}{P(X=k)} \\
&= P(Y=n-k) \\
&= e^{-3}\frac{3^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}
\end{align*}

but again, I'm confused to how this is equal to:

\begin{align*} 
T-k&\mid X=k \sim\operatorname{Poisson}(3) \\
T-X&\mid X \sim\operatorname{Poisson}(3) 
\end{align*}

Comment: The sum of finitely many independent Poisson variates with means $\lambda_i$ is another Poisson variate with mean $\sum\lambda_i$.

Comment: Are we supposed to assume  $T=X+Y$?

Comment: @kimchilover my bad just edited it in

Comment: An aside - your notion is a little off. For events $A,B$, the expression $P(A) \cap P(B)$ doesn't really make sense - probabilities are numbers, how do you take intersection? However, $A \cap B$ is an event, and so $P(A\cap B)$ does make sense. So, e.g., I'd write $P( \{X = k\} \cap \{T = n\}),$ or the common shorthand $P(X = k, T = n)$ which usually means the same thing, but not $P(X = k) \cap P(T = n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X,Y$ be independent Poisson variates with parameters $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$. Then $T=X+Y$ is a Poisson variate with parameter $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$. This is because the $MGF$ of $T$ is$$M_T(\theta)=E[e^{\theta(X+Y)}]=M_X(\theta)\cdot M_Y(\theta)=e^{(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)(e^\theta-1)}$$So in your case,$$\frac{P(X=k)\cdot P(Y=n-k)}{P(T=n)}=\frac{\left(\frac{2^ke^{-2}}{k!}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{3^{n-k}e^{-3}}{(n-k)!}\right)}{\left(\frac{5^ne^{-5}}{n!}\right)}=\binom nk\left(\frac25\right)^k\left(\frac35\right)^{n-k}$$For your second question,$$P(T=n|X=k)=P(T-X=n-k|X=k)=e^{-3}\cdot\frac{3^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}$$ $\forall n\ge k$, and hence$$P(T-X=m|X=k)=e^{-3}\cdot\frac{3^m}{m!}~\forall m\in\Bbb Z_{\ge0}$$indicating that $T-X|X$ is a Poisson variate with $\lambda=3$.